# Not Seeding - For Beginners

Tags: bittorrent, p2p, peer-to-peer, qbittorrent

I have downloaded a file using qBittorrent. However, it does not seem to be seeding - I know the difference between seeders, peechers, and leechers - and there are no upload limits. Also, I am using a P2P-friendly VPN.



1. In the first image, you can see that there is 1 (2) peers, however, surely that means the torrent should be uploading to that peer?
[image: Image 1]


2. In the second image, there is 0 (2) peers, which means that I have no peers to upload it to? Am I correct in saying that?
[image: Image 2]



3. Also, for Peers, it fluctuates between 0, 1, 2 yet it's barely uploading. Why exactly would that be happening?


One last thing, I downloaded a file yesterday using qBittorrent and I managed to seed 1.15 for the Ratio after a couple hours. So I think it is just this specific file and the Peers. A good and clear explanation would be greatly appreciated as I am new to this.

Comment: How big is the file? Are you using a seedbox or your home network?

Comment: Based on the status of that particular torrent, there isn't anyone seeding due to nobody having the entire file.  The `[F]` is an indication that you have forced the client to seed the torrent.  If none of the peers need the segments of the torrent you have then you have nothing to seed.

Comment: @MrEthernet I am using my home network

Comment: @Ramhound So is that whats happening - nobody needs the file, hence it's not being uploaded to anyone?

Comment: That's how [P2P](https://www.binance.vision/blockchain/peer-to-peer-networks-explained) works essentially. If no one needs the file you aren't seeding anything.

Comment: @MarkPrescher - It's either a case of no peers needing the fragments of the torrent you have or peers being unable to connect to you.  Difficult to determine what actually is going on, based on the information, you have provided us.

Comment: @CaldeiraG I understand that thank you, so how would I exactly know that nobody needs the file - by looking at the number in the Peers column?

Comment: @Ramhound I understand thanks. I am not sure why they wouldn't be able to connect to me if that is the problem. I am testing seeding on a popular torrent now.

Comment: Your torrent client usually shows a warning when it cannot seed. Since you're behind a vpn you need to check if which ports are open.

Comment: @MarkPrescher - There any number of reasons a peer could not connect to you.  Firewall settings and incompatible clients used by the peers are just two of those reasons.  Just because you have a small number of connections does not mean your ports are open

Comment: @CaldeiraG It seems no ports are open... even port 80 is closed -  I am using a VPN

Comment: @Ramhound Will do some more research on Firewall settings. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. In the first image, you can see that there is 1 (2) peers, however, surely that means the torrent should be uploading to that peer?

Yes indeed, but maybe it's just a count problem and not a real seeder.

> 2. In the second image, there is 0 (2) peers, which means that I have no peers to upload it to? Am I correct in saying that?

Yes it's right and as you are seeding, if there is no leecher (Peers), nobody wants your file so you don't seed.

> 3. Also, for Peers, it fluctuates between 0, 1, 2 yet it's barely uploading. Why exactly would that be happening?

I don't understand very well your question.

If I were you, I'd try doing this:

1. Download a torrent on a public tracker with a lot of leecher and seeders like [Ubuntu torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.10/ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent). For this test, don't use your VPN. Observate if you can seed correctly.
2. Quit qBittorrent and turn on your VPN. Select a server with TCP connection, observe if the problem is the same.
3. Quit qBittorrent and turn on your VPN. Select a server with UDP connection, observe if the problem is the same.
4. Check the torrent information of the torrent which make problem. Look at the protocol used by the tracker. I had the problem on a tracker, UDP was used and my VPN was TCP so I couldn't download files. You can eventually use [Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com/) to check if qBittorrent don't show you the information.

Comment: Thanks for the great and detailed response! I really appreciate it, and thanks for the great explanations! :D